# image in the imageview is not in the center when the gravity is center

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview

The Image inside of the imageview is not centered when the gravity applied is the center. why isn't my image centered?
Here is my code

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/back" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
      </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: why do you have scaleType matrix? try to change to centerCrop

Comment: I need to use matrix

Comment: what do you want to do and you need matrix? If you explain me maybe I could help you.

Comment: @vspallas thanks. according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238505/two-bitmaps-merge-wrongly-in-wrong-postion I need to have matrix. if I use other scale type I got wrong result. you can read mt last comment on that topic to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using scale type matrix. And scale type matrix always write image from x=0 and y=0. And if you want to place image in center then you have to remove scale type matrix. Or if you want to use scale type then you can use android:scaleType = "center" / android:scaleType ="centerInside" according to your requirement.
                      So simple by removing scale type matrix you can place your imageview in center. Thanks

Comment: OK. I know this but I need to use matrix. maybe I should crop picture before I set it to imageview

Comment: please tell me your complete requirements. What do u want to do actually may be after that i will be help you better

Comment: I want to merge to picture using this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238505/two-bitmaps-merge-wrongly-in-wrong-position and for merging both image should use matrix. and if I use anther scale type  the merging done in wrong postilion. so I need to use matrix .

Comment: some thing like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.km.topphotobackgrounds merge background and the other picture

Answer (score 0):

layout_gravity means its position(ImageView) in its parent.

scaleType is propertiy that control show method of src image.

So you should replace the code "android:scaleType="matrix""android:scaletype = "center"